# Collection of a Type using a Generic Type of any kind

Tags: c#, generics, collections, types

I have this issue I feel could be resolved any number of ways, but am not sure what the most efficient approach is.  This same issue was idenfitied on SO at [collection of different generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456702/collection-of-different-generic-types), but there didn't seem to be any resolutions.  I would like to resurrect this question and pick the brains of the experts!

In my case I have a contract:

```
public interface IServiceInvoker<TServiceContract>
{
}
```

There's actually an abstract class involved in this too to centralize some of the core code, but I'm not going to include that here so that the question doesn't become overly complicated.

The type TServiceContract can be any service interface.  It's therefore not limited to any specific type as the implementing class will validate the service, etc.  I then have this class (ServiceDAO below) to encapsulate basic use of this and other references.  I'm trying to create a collection property of the IServiceInvoker type, but am having no luck... Basically what I have is:

```
public class ServiceDAO
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _serviceInvocationCollection = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ServiceInvocationCollection
    {
        get { return _serviceInvocationCollection.AsEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>(); }
        private set { _serviceInvocationCollection = value as Dictionary<string, object>; }
    }
}
```

I would rather the collection be of the type of IServiceInvoker, but can't specify the of type TServiceContract at the class level since the collection could use any number implementing classes of IServiceInvoker... using object instead seems to be too loosely typed... any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe define a base interface that the generic one inherits from; then you can make the collection `Dictionary<string, IServiceInvoker>`.

```
public interface IServiceInvoker { }
public interface IServiceInvoker<TServiceContract> : IServiceInvoker
{
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a restriction to the `TServiceContract` type parameter, say `IServiceContract`, and use `Dictionary<string, IServiceInvoker<IServiceContract>>`.  But then of course every service would have to inherit `IServiceContract`.

```
public interface IServiceContract { }
public interface IServiceInvoker<TServiceContract>
    where TServiceContract : IServiceContract
{
}
```

Comment: I had wondered about that, but wasn't sure if I would be adding more overhead than necessary and overly complicating it... is this pretty well the standard way of handling such a situation?

Comment: @bjhuffine I think it's either that or restrict the type parameter (see above).

Comment: It's hard to argue when two respond with a similar response.  At least by having the generic interface implementing a non-generic interface, I can better control type safety for the TServiceContract type and keep from having to have every service implement an IServiceContract... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Simple approach

Just add another interface that is not generic:

```
public interface IServiceInvokerUntyped
{
}

public interface IServiceInvoker<TServiceContract> : IServiceInvokerUntyped
{
}
```

Declare the dictionary it like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, IServiceInvokerUntyped> _serviceInvocationCollection = new Dictionary<string, IServiceInvokerUntyped>();
```

---

### Variant approach

If your generic type parameter can be declared as covariant:

```
public interface IServiceInvoker<out T> : IServiceInvokerUntyped
{
}
```

Declare the dictionary it like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, IServiceInvoker<object>> _serviceInvocationCollection = new Dictionary<string, IServiceInvoker<object>>();
```

For contravariance, just change 'out' to 'in' and modify the dictionary declaration/initialization as appropriate.

Comment: Looks like similar suggestions... so maybe this is the approach?  See comments for @McGarnagle

Comment: Yes maybe. I would just go with the simple approach above and not use generics unless it's needed for other reasons.

Comment: I like what you did with the Variant Approach. With that approach though is the out keyword and the implementation of IServiceInvokerUntyped necessary in that case? Then I could just use Dictionary<string, IServiceInvoker<object>> Edit: of course hindsight I guess is that by using the Simple Approach I can ensure even greater type safety of the TServiceContract type.

Comment: The out keyword (for **CO**-variance) is needed, but it should only be used in the interface declaration, not in the field type declaration. IServiceInvokerUntyped is not necessary if all your types inherit the variant interface. Note that variant types are restricted in how they can be used (so it might be better to use the simple approach unless variance is actually appropriate for other reasons).

Comment: Ok... that makes sense and does seem to be the path of least resistance and potential future headaches.  Thanks for your help!